# Python unpack binary data, numeric of length 12

Tags: python, struct, binaries

I have a file with big endian binaries.  There are two numeric fields.  The first has length 8 and the second length 12.  How can I unpack the two numbers?

I am using the Python module struct (https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and it works for the first field

```
num1 = struct.unpack('>Q',payload[0:8])
```

but I don't know how I can unpack the second number.  If I treat it as char(12), then I get something like `'\x00\xe3AC\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01'`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a number stored on 12 bytes?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: there are 2 numbers to be unpacked, one has length 8 and the second has length 12.  num1 I can unpack as stated above.  I am having trouble with the second.  I am looking for the first argument, x, of struct.unpack(x,payload[8:20]).

Comment: My bad, I misread the question (and deleted a wrong comment that I enter because of it) 
Have you tried treating it as three ints?:
`struct.unpack('>hhh', payload[8:20])` What do you get if you do that?

Comment: '>hhh' gives struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 6. When i change it to '>hhhhhh', then '\x00\xe3AC\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01' becomes (227, 16707, 0, 8, 0, 1). But I think it should be a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a new string of bytes for the second number of length 16, fill the last 12 bytes with the string of bytes that hold your number and first 4 ones with zeros.

Then decode the bytestring with unpack with format `>QQ`, let's say to `numHI`, `numLO` variables. Then, you get final number with that: `number = numHI * 2^64 + numLO`*. AFAIR the integers in Python can be (almost) as large as you wish, so you will have no problems with overflows. That's only rough idea, please comment if you have problems with writing that in actual Python code, I'll then edit my answer to provide more help.

*^ is in this case the math power, so please use math.pow. Alternatively, you can use byte shift: `number = numHI << 64 + numLO`.

Comment: I think that worked! Starting with string='\x00\xe3AC\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01', I created x='0000'+string, then I unpack numHI,numLO= unpack('>QQ',x).  Using your formula above, I get number=6944656625227956935. Unfortunately, I cannot check right now if that number is right.

Comment: I'm glad. Also, I have made small edit-you can use byte shift instead of power :)

Comment: thanks for your help. one thing. `number = numHI * 2^64 + numLO` is a lot faster than `number = numHI << 64 + numLO`

Comment: That's strange, I would say that binary operations are faster :).

Comment: i agree, in general. though my machine had difficulties with <<64. anyway, the important thing is that i got the number.